# I'm confused about Vue createapp() function. It says "it creates a new application instance". What is an application instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm confused about Vue createapp() function. It says "it creates a new application instance". What is an **Application instance**?

```
const app = Vue.createApp()
```

Answer (score 2):

Application Instance, is your Vue app.

> You are not limited to a single application instance on the same page.
> The createApp API allows multiple Vue applications to co-exist on the
> same page, each with its own scope for configuration and global
> assets:

```
const app1 = createApp({
  /* ... */
})
app1.mount('#container-1')

const app2 = createApp({
  /* ... */
})
app2.mount('#container-2')
```

Check [Multiple application instances](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#app-configurations)